# How to pass a method name to actionListner

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need your help in passing the proper method to the button actionListner. I am having a button in a datatable. The button code is below:

```
<h:commandButton id="submitButton" value="View" actionListener="#{bcd.showDatailDialog}" >
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{c}" target="#{bcd.selectedRequest}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Based on the value of the `#{c.documentType}` which is displayed in the datatable, it will decide which method to be used in the actionListner.

The `showDatailDialog` method code is:

```
public String showDatailDialog(String sdoc) {

private String methodName; 

try {

if (sdoc.equalsIgnoreCase("CE")) {

mthodName="#{bcd.BCESS}";

}
else
{
mthodName="#{bcd.BSSES}";   
}

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return methodName;
    }
```

Now when I click on the button, it showed me an error:

```
<ActionListenerImpl> <processAction> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: //C:/../JDeveloper/../XXX.war/jsf/Search.jsf @91,89 action="#{bcd.showDetailDialog}": Method not found: rfc.Bean3@355f70.showDetailDialog()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching this problem wrongly. The `actionListener` (and `action`) attributes must represent a method expression, not a value expression. Right now you're treating it as if it were a value expression returning a method expression. This isn't going to work.

Just let it invoke a real method which in turn delegates further to the desired method.

```
<h:dataTable ... var="item">
   ...
   <h:commandButton ... action="#{bean.action(item)}" />
```

```
public void action(Item item) {
    if (item.getType() == Type.FOO) { // It's of course an enum.
        oneMethod(item);
    } else {
        otherMethod(item);
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-parameter-of-current-row-to-commandlink-inside-datatable)
- [Is it possible to use EL conditional operator in action attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473743/is-it-possible-to-use-el-conditional-operator-in-action-attribute/)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)

Answer (score 0):

`showDatailDialog` method in your code expects one `String` parameter, so just use it like this

```
actionListener="#{bcd.showDatailDialog(c.documentType)}"
```